# Difference between 'Object obj = new Object()' and 'Object obj = null' in static and non static function

Tags: java, object, static, null

I am have the following code

```
public class Sample {   
    public static void display(){
        System.out.println("Hai Sample");   
    }
    public void displays(){
         System.out.println("Hai Sample");  
    }
}

public class Sample2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample obj=null;
        obj.display();
        obj.displays();
        }
}
```

Here, When we use assign null to Sample obj I can access only static method. If I use new operator like `Sample obj= new Sample();` I can access both static and non static method.

Here My question is, How object initialization happens here and How null refers Sample object's static methods and why not non static method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that in one case (`new Sample()`), you have an instance. In the second case (`null`), you **don't**.

`display` is a static method (related to the class, not any instance); `displays` is an *instance* method (related to a specific instance). It's a quirk of Java syntax that you're allowed to refer to `static` fields and methods through something that *looks* like an instance reference. Since the instance isn't actually used, it's not dereferenced, and so the fact it's `null` doesn't cause any trouble.

Your code in `main` is *actually* this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sample obj=null;
    Sample.display();  // `display` is static, no instance is used
    obj.displays();    // `displays` is non-static, requires an instance
}
```

When you seem to call `display` through `obj`, in fact all the compiler uses the `obj` variable for is to see what its type is (in this case, `Sample`). The *value* of the variable (`null` or an instance, either way) isn't used at all, and there's no error.

In contrast, calling `displays`, the `obj` variable is used both for its type (`Sample`) **and** its value, because when calling `displays` the JVM needs a reference to use as `this` for the call. Attempting to call an instance method with a `null` reference is an error.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike for an instance member, you don't need an actual instance of the class to access a `static` member.

So, where you do:

```
obj.display();
```

this is considered by the JVM as:

```
Sample.display();
```

and will run without a problem.

An instance member, however, is depending on (and unique for each) instance of the class. It doesn't exist, untill the instance is made.

```
obj.display();
```

is code you should never write: someone who might have to maintain your code later on, might mistake it for an instance member, and assume that the impact of calling that method is limited to that instance alone, which it is not.

As for the nuts and bolts on the creation of a new instance, check the page on the topic in the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

Answer (score 1):

Static methods can be accessed through the class, there is no need to instantiate. But you have to get an instance of the class to access no static methods.

Should view this solved question: [What does the 'static' keyword do in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413898/what-does-the-static-keyword-do-in-a-class)

Answer (score 1):

> Here My question is, How object initialization happens here and How null refers Sample object's static methods

It doesn't!
null is null.

You can allways call static methods without creating any object.

Also, you should call static methods in a static way:

```
Sample.display();
```

A good IDE should give you a warning/error the way you are accessing the method:

> The static method display() from the type Sample should be accessed in a static way

Answer (score 1):

When -

```
Sample obj=null;
```

And you are trying to access ,

```
public void display() {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

It will show error. It requires an instance. But you can call this -

```
public static void display(){
    System.out.println("Success");   
}
```

As it is static , no instance is required.